# prevent object from instantiation in fluent builder pattern C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns, builder-pattern

i am trying to create fluent builder pattern to create user request as it has lot of parameters. for simplicity i am just showing few parameters

Here is my request class or the model

```
public class Request
    {
        public string UserName {  get; set; }

        public string Password {  get; set; }

        public string Token {  get; set; }


    }
```

Here is my builder class that build the requests.

```
 public class RequestBuilder
    {
        private string _username;
        private string _password;
        private string _token;

        public RequestBuilder UserName(string username)
        {
            _username = username;
            return this;

        }

        public RequestBuilder Password(string password)
        {
            _password = password;
            return this;

        }

        public RequestBuilder Token(string token)
        {
            _token = token;
            return this;

        }

        public static implicit operator Request(RequestBuilder requestBuilder)
        {

            return new Request()
            {

                UserName = requestBuilder._username,
                Password = requestBuilder._password,
                Token = requestBuilder._token

            };
        }
    }
```

At a glance this approach might look working but it has security holes like

1. User can create Request direct using `Request request = new Request()`
2. if i restric the request class by implementing the parameterized constructor in Request class

   ```
    public Request(RequestBuilder rb){                      
           UserName = rb._username;
           Password = rb._password;
           Token    = rb._token;                    
    }
   ```

In this case i need to create `set` and `get` method in `RequestBuilder` which will eventually expose `RequestBuilder` as follows

```
RequestBuilder rb = new RequestBuilder();
rb._username ="test";
```

so can anyone tell me how shall i protect `Request` class preventing from instantiation.

Comment: You can use the "internal" access modifier so that only other code within the same assembly can invoke the constructor. Of course, ultimately a hacker would be able to figure out your data structure and service URL - so this shouldn't be confused with security. This merely restricts things at an API level for those of us playing by the rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to find the solution and end up with the following

1. using `Builder` as nested class
2. making `Request` class default constructor private. However, `Builder` is a nested class it can access request class and instantiate it
3. In order to create the object of `Request` class user has to go through the `Builder` only.

> Request request = new
>   Request.Builder().UserName("user").Password("abc").Build();

**Sample code**

```
public class Request
    {
        public string UserName {   get; private set; }

        public string Password {  get; private set; }

        public string Token { get; private set; }


        private Request(){




        }

        public class Builder
        {

            private Request request = new Request();

            public Builder UserName(string username)
            {
                request.UserName = username;
                return this;

            }

            public Builder Password(string password)
            {
                request.Password = password;
                return this;

            }

            public Builder Token(string token)
            {
                request.Token = token;
                return this;

            }


            public Request Build()
            {

                return request;
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: perfect solution